# Implementing a Short Five Star Rating System in Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

At any given time the code below displays five consecutive stars. These are either a `star1.png` (yellow) or a `star0.png` (black). When the user hovers over, say, the third star, the first three stars are to turn into `star1.png` (yellow), with the remaining two stars being `star0.png` (black).

The code works *initially*, with some `[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected` warnings when hovering over a star, until eventually hovering over a different star causes

- `[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')"`
- `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')`

I'm not certain what is causing this, and would appreciate help in figuring it out.

```
<template>
  <div class="col-sm border-right">
    <span v-for="n in rating" :key="n">
      <img src="../assets/star1.png" style="width: 6vh;" @mouseover="stars(n)">
    </span>
    <span v-for="m in 5-rating" :key="m">
      <img src="../assets/star0.png" style="width: 6vh;" @mouseover="stars(m)">
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      rating: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    stars(n){
      this.rating = n;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the keys your using (`n` and `m`) are the same.
The key attribute is used by vue.js to track each node's identity and should be unique across all the nodes of the same parent.
Both `v-for` loops use numbers as keys, which leads to a conflict because the same number can appear in both loops.

```html
<template>
  <div class="col-sm border-right">
    <!-- First loop for yellow stars -->
    <span v-for="n in rating" :key="'filled-' + n">
      <img src="../assets/star1.png" style="width: 6vh;" @mouseover="stars(n)">
    </span>
    <!-- Second loop for black stars -->
    <span v-for="m in 5-rating" :key="'empty-' + m">
      <img src="../assets/star0.png" style="width: 6vh;" @mouseover="stars(m)">
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      rating: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    stars(n){
      this.rating = n;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```